# How can i download .xml files and parse a webpage(e.g. html) using Java?

Tags: java, xml, rss

I have a work to do. Firstly, my program will be given an argument. This argument will contain Websites where I can find RSS Feeds(for instance: [CnnRssFeeds](http://edition.cnn.com/services/rss/)). Then, I have to visit these sites and download the RSS Feeds(I think these files would usually be `.xml` files, right?).

After, I have to save the `.xml` files in a folder on my disk and finally I have to manage them using the Rome library of Java. I will extract some information such as: title, author, description, link etc.

Could you help me? I have some trouble when I want to visit each site and download(save) the RSS (as I said above, they are usually `.xml` files)

Comment: What is your problem? What have you done so far?

Comment: @AlexR : When i visit a Website where i can find RssFeeds, such as the one i posted above, i want to download the RssFeeds(they are usually .xml files). How can i download these RssFeeds??

Comment: @limas - A tiny bit of research (e.g. a simple search of SO) would have answered these questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download and save a file from internet using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java)

Comment: @ Stephen C: I checked the link. Thank you for your time. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For downloading files you can use the first answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java) question.(I have tried it works :))

And for parsing XML u can use XPath.XPath is used to navigate through elements and attributes in an XML document.[This](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/xPath/java-xpath.shtml) tutorial of XPath seems to be pretty well

Comment: @ narek.gevorgyan: Thank you. I will try to solve my problem using your advice or i will get back posting my trouble.

Comment: @ narek.gevorgyan: Thank you again. Your post helped me and is exactly the one part of a process i need to do.

Answer (score 1):

why so many question marks?
If you know to visit site you do not have a problem to *download* content of any resource. Your problem is parse HTML and extract the URL of RSS feed. The feed is embedded into the HTML page using `link` tag:

`<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="My Feed" href="/feeds/myfeed" />`

So, you have to parse the HTML. There are several ways to do this. For example you can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) or other you like. Once you are able to parse HTML you can extract value of the `href` attribute (`/feeds/myfeed` in our example.) Now just construct the full URL (concatenate URL of your page with `/feeds/myfeed` and download the resource.

Comment: @ AlexR: Thank you. This is the one part of an answer i am lookinf for solving my problem. It worked ;-)

Comment: @limas, what's the second part you are looking for?

Comment: The second part was to download an .xml or .html page. This issue was answered just in the post below. Could i ask you something about parsing a webpage?? I want to extract only the rss hrefs among all the hrefs containing in a page. Is there any attribute to differ rss hrefs from other hrefs?? I want to get rss hrefs from different rssFeeds Websites.

Comment: According to the structure of rss hrefs , i can see that the name of a rss shown on a Website is placed just before the suffix: /rss.xml. So, is this a way to identify rss hrefs ??

Comment: Actually, i realised that there is no a general strategy to find out the rss links of every rssFeeds website. It depends on the structure of the website. Finally, i would like to thank you for everything.